# Appending onto QList<QFile*>

Tags: c++, qt, raii

I was wondering why when you make a QList of QFIle you must make them pointers. For example I have a class that has a QList< QFile* >:

```
class Files
{
public:
   void AddFile(QString newFile);

private:
QList<QFile*> files;
}
```

Now when AddFIle is called it does this:

```
QFile* newt = new QFile(new_File);
files += newf;
```

Why am I not able to change the QList< QFile* > into QList< QFile >? Every time I try and do that I get an error:

**QFIle::QFile(const QFile&) is private**

Here is what the code looks like when I change it to QList< QFile >:

```
class Files
{
public:
   void AddFile(QString newFile);

private:
QList<QFile> files;
}
```

Then the .cpp

```
QFile newt(new_File);
files += newf;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QFile` type must be used as `*QFile` in your example because the author made the copy constructor private. The `QList` type needs access to a copy constructor of its template parameter. The `QFile`'s copy constructor cannot be accessed, but the `QFile*` type has an accessible copy constructor.

This was most likely intentional. It is probably unsafe to make copies of a `QFile` object.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: becasue it is dangerous to copy a QFile object, the authors made it impossible to copy (by making the copy constructor private).

Long answer:

1. Qt internal handling of QObjects: Most non-trivial Qt objects are heap generated, and [many of them](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html) have special internal variables that, when used right, allows their memory (and life, and references) to be managed internally by Qt. So the preferred way of handling Qt objects is as a pointer. Qt provides multiple [smart pointers](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2009/08/25/count-with-me-how-many-smart-pointer-classes-does-qt-have/) for ease of use.
2. Resource handling in general: Another reason is that, even without Qt's internal structures, sharing *copies* of resource objects without using handles is a bad idea.

Comment: It is not dangerous to copy a QFile object. It is impossible to do so, because the authors of the object forbid that. If QObject, QIODevice, QFileDevice and QFile were designed to be copyable, it'd be fine, but it'd be fairly useless anyway.

Comment: @KubaOber yes it is impossible by design... and the dangers of copying a resource object and mismanaging it because you have multiple copies lying around is the reason it was designed to be impossible. edited in. And it is not just useless - it can be downright dangerous from a memory and consistency standpoint.

Comment: @Fox It'd only be dangerous if you designed it to be dangerous. A resource object designed to be copied is not supposed to mismanage anything, it's supposed to "just work". It can be designed the be perfectly safe yet perfectly useless, because there are really no sane semantics for such a behavior that everyone would instinctively agree on. Thus almost everyone would use it in a way that is not aligned with their expectation of behavior, and thus wrong. In case of QObject hierarchy, it was a design decision motivated by human aspects of software design. There's no technical reason at all.

Comment: so, there are a couple of mental models you can look at:
1. I have one resource object and I can pass a handle to multiple objects, so if I close it from one handle (I handwave concurrency and other simultaneity dangers here), it thankfully refreshes the 'central' object and is visible from other handles.
2. I implement copy-semantics and go through each resource property and think about how original.property should relate to copy.property when _one_ of them changes. 
I'm mentioning it is dangerous, only because there are multiple mental models to #2, and switching betw them messes things up

Comment: in a nutshell, I'd be perfectly fine if a copy were simply _useless_. The pitfalls of having multiple objects represent (as opposed to refer to) one single resource with mutable states are way too many... and relate badly back to real world analogies. An implementation would necessarily have a -skewed- inconsistent mental model compared to expectation and therefore be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple: QList is a bit "deficient" in that it only supports copyable objects. QObjects are non-copyable. A `QFile` is a QObject. That's all there's to it.

### C++11's std::list Does Support QObject

If you use C++11 and have a container that supports in-place construction and doesn't need to copy nor default-construct the objects it holds, you can *certainly* store object instances in it. The below works with both Qt 4 and Qt 5:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <list>

int main()
{
   std::list<QFile> files;
   files.emplace_back(QDir::homePath() + QDir::separator() + "test.txt");
   files.front().open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   files.front().write("abcdef\n");
}
```

### Why is QFile non-copyable?

Think of what QObject has to do, and then think of what the semantics of a copy would be. Make sure you've taken account of threading and signals and slots. You then realize that almost every person who thinks of copying a QObject would come up with differing semantics of what's expected for such a QObject copy to do. Thus it'd be virtually useless, since people routinely ignore documentation, and there'd be bugs galore due to this. I know myself since I did at one point modify my own copy of Qt to allow QObject copying. Eventually it turned out to be completely counterproductive in any but most trivial cases. Now let's not forget that we've only touched on semantics of QObject copying.

Don't forget to that a QFile is a QIODevice, and as such it has internal buffers. Now tell me what you expect this piece of code to produce:

```
QFile foo("file");
foo.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
foo.write("foo");
QFile bar(foo);
bar.write("bar");
bar.close();
foo.close();
```

Now suppose that you've changed the order of `close()` calls:

```
bar.close();
foo.close();
```

This is just for writing. Now suppose we have this code:

```
QTcpSocket socket;
socket.connectToHost("localhost", 8080);
socket.waitForConnected(); // do not use it in production code!!
QTcpSocket socket2(socket);
qDebug() << socket.read(3);
qDebug() << socket2.read(3);
```

Given that the other side of the connection has sent "abcdef", what do you expect
the output to be?

In other words: you do not want to be able to copy a QIODevice.